# Screen brightness reset to minimum after every reboot on HP Pavilon DV4. HELP

Tags: 13.10, screen, brightness, hp

Ubuntu 13.10 doesn't save my brightness settings between sessions. Everytime I boot up, the brightness is always at zero, and I always have to set it back to my preferred setting (at maximum). How can I ensure that my brightness preference will persist after reboot? I am using a HP pavilion dv4. I see where this question has been answered but no one gives step by step instructions on how to get it completed. Thank you